# KOTLIN: Can I Call Multiple Class Methods Outside Apply block and Difference in Calling Methods Inside and Outside of Apply Block?

Tags: kotlin

```
package com.example.learning

fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    var person = Person("Ramu", 51, 50000F, 7.5F)

    person.apply{
        name = "Sam"
        id = 1
        details()
    }.details()
}
```

**Q1)What is the difference in calling details or any class method inside and outside the apply block?**

**Q2)Here in the apply block can I call multiple class methods at once like calling Salary and Details at the same time outside the apply block with .details()&.salary()?**

```
class Person(var name: String, var id: Int, var sal: Float, var salRaise: Float){
    fun details(){
        println("The name of the person is $name with id $id and salary if $sal")
    }

    fun salary(): Float{
        sal *= salRaise
        return sal
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`apply` is just a convenience method so you don't have to write `person` every time.

This:

```
person.apply{
    name = "Sam"
    id = 1
    details()
}
```

is the same as doing:

```
person.name = "Sam"
person.id = 1
person.details()
```

I'm not sure what you mean by your second question. You ask how to call those 2 methods outside a apply? Just do

```
person.details()
person.salary()
```

There's another benefit to using apply. If `person` could be null you could do `person?.apply` to only change those fields in the case the person is not null. So this for example:

```
fun changePerson(person : Person?) {
    person?.apply{
        name = "Sam"
        id = 1
        details()
    }
}
```

is the same as

```
fun changePerson(person : Person?) {
    if (person != null) {
        person.name = "Sam"
        person.id = 1
        person.details()
    }
}
```

EDIT:

If you want to be able to chain the salary() after a details() you could do it by making this change:

```
class Person(var name: String, var id: Int, var sal: Float, var salRaise: Float){
    fun details() : Person{
        println("The name of the person is $name with id $id and salary if $sal")
        return this
    }

    fun salary(): Float{
        sal *= salRaise
        return sal
    }
}
```

then you could do this for example:

```
person.apply{
    name = "Sam"
    id = 1
}.details().salary()
```

Comment: By Outside I meant                                                                                             
    `person.apply{
        println("Apply Block")
        name = "Chachu"
        id = 1
    }.details()
        .salary()`

Comment: @Snehasisbasu just write it on the next line like `person.salary()`

Comment: No No I know that we can write in the next line, I was just asking Can we do that. So we cannot do that, Ok thankyou very much

Comment: @Snehasisbasu see also my edit

Comment: This New edit is giving "Kotlin: Unresolved reference: salary" Error